Raymarcher glitches when performing local transforms using modulus "coordinate-space" repeat trick
I am building a ray marcher in GLSL to further understand the language. I am attempting to repeat the coordinate space using modulus when calculating the SDF so that "infinite" spheres appear. When trying to change each of the spheres position (within their local coordinate space), the ray marching glitches out and I have no idea why. Any help would be incredible. Here is the code and an image showing the glitching (bottom right corner)enter image description here
precision mediump float;

#define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795

uniform float u_time;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform vec2 u_mouse;

const int maxsteps = 100;
const float srfdist = 0.001;
const float maxdist = 100.0;

const float ff = 20.;
const float oo = .3;
const float s = 2.;

const vec3 bg = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

float linstep(float min1, float max1, float value) {
  return (value - min1) * (1.) / (max1 - min1);
}

float rand(float n){return fract(sin(n) * 43758.5453123);}
vec3 random3(vec3 c) {
    float j = 4096.0*sin(dot(c,vec3(17.0, 59.4, 15.0)));
    vec3 r;
    r.z = fract(512.0*j);
    j *= .125;
    r.x = fract(512.0*j);
    j *= .125;
    r.y = fract(512.0*j);
    return r-0.5;
}

float hash(float n) { return fract(sin(n) * 1e4); }
float hash(vec2 p) { return fract(1e4 * sin(17.0 * p.x + p.y * 0.1) * (0.1 + abs(sin(p.y * 13.0 + p.x)))); }

float noise(float x) {
    float i = floor(x);
    float f = fract(x);
    float u = f * f * (3.0 - 2.0 * f);
    return mix(hash(i), hash(i + 1.0), u);
}


float mod289(float x){return x - floor(x * (1.0 / 289.0)) * 289.0;}
vec4 mod289(vec4 x){return x - floor(x * (1.0 / 289.0)) * 289.0;}
vec4 perm(vec4 x){return mod289(((x * 34.0) + 1.0) * x);}

float noise(vec3 p){
    vec3 a = floor(p);
    vec3 d = p - a;
    d = d * d * (3.0 - 2.0 * d);

    vec4 b = a.xxyy + vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    vec4 k1 = perm(b.xyxy);
    vec4 k2 = perm(k1.xyxy + b.zzww);

    vec4 c = k2 + a.zzzz;
    vec4 k3 = perm(c);
    vec4 k4 = perm(c + 1.0);

    vec4 o1 = fract(k3 * (1.0 / 41.0));
    vec4 o2 = fract(k4 * (1.0 / 41.0));

    vec4 o3 = o2 * d.z + o1 * (1.0 - d.z);
    vec2 o4 = o3.yw * d.x + o3.xz * (1.0 - d.x);

    return o4.y * d.y + o4.x * (1.0 - d.y);
}

mat4 rotationMatrix(vec3 axis, float angle) {
    axis = normalize(axis);
    float s = sin(angle);
    float c = cos(angle);
    float oc = 1.0 - c;
    
    return mat4(oc * axis.x * axis.x + c,           oc * axis.x * axis.y - axis.z * s,  oc * axis.z * axis.x + axis.y * s,  0.0,
                oc * axis.x * axis.y + axis.z * s,  oc * axis.y * axis.y + c,           oc * axis.y * axis.z - axis.x * s,  0.0,
                oc * axis.z * axis.x - axis.y * s,  oc * axis.y * axis.z + axis.x * s,  oc * axis.z * axis.z + c,           0.0,
                0.0,                                0.0,                                0.0,                                1.0);
}

vec3 rotate(vec3 v, vec3 axis, float angle) {
    mat4 m = rotationMatrix(axis, angle);
      return (m * vec4(v, 1.0)).xyz;
}

float smoothMax(float a, float b, float k){
    return log(exp(k*a)+exp(k*b))/k;
}

float smoothMin(float a, float b, float k){
    return - smoothMax(-a,-b,k);
}

float sdfsphere(vec3 p, float s){
    return length(p)-s;
}

float sdfbox( vec3 p, vec3 s ){
  vec3 q = abs(p) - s;
  return length(max(q,0.0)) + min(max(q.x,max(q.y,q.z)),0.0);
}

float sdfrbox( vec3 p, vec3 s, float r )
{
  vec3 q = abs(p) - s + r;
  return length(max(q,0.0)) + min(max(q.x,max(q.y,q.z)),0.0) - r;
}

float map(vec3 p){
    float plane = p.y+.5;
    float s0 = sdfsphere(p,.3);

    float s = 4.;
    vec3 p0 = p;
    float ix = floor(p0.x/s)+52.;
    float iz = p0.z/s;
    //p0.y = p0.y + u_time*5.*rand(ix+320.);
    vec3 p1 = mod(p0,s)-vec3(s/2.);

    p1.y -= .5;

    s0 = sdfsphere(p1,.5);

    float sdfval = s0;
    return sdfval;
}

vec3 normal(vec3 p){
    vec2 e = vec2(.001,0);

    vec3 n = vec3(
        map(p+e.xyy)-map(p-e.xyy),
        map(p+e.yxy)-map(p-e.yxy),
        map(p+e.yyx)-map(p-e.yyx));

    return normalize(n);
}

float shadow( in vec3 ro, in vec3 rd, float mint, float maxt, float k )
{
    float res = 1.;
    float t = mint;
    for( int i=0; i<256; i++ )
    {   
        if(t>maxt) break;
        float h = map(ro + rd*t);
        if( h<0.001 )
            return 0.0;
        res = min(res,k*h/t);
        t += h;
    }
    return res;
}

float getlight(vec3 p,vec3 n,vec3 lp){
    vec3 lightp = lp;
    vec3 l = normalize(lightp-p);

    float shad = shadow(p+n*.1,normalize(lightp-p),.001,100.,4.);

    float dt = dot(n,l);
    float diff = max(0.,dt);
    diff = smoothstep(-.2,1.6,dt);
    // diff = smoothstep(-0.5,1.,dt);

    return diff*shad;
}

vec3 raymarch(vec3 ro, vec3 rd){
    float totdist = 0.;

    for(int i=0; i<maxsteps; i++){
        vec3 p = ro + rd*totdist;
        float d2srf = map(p);
        if(totdist>maxdist){
            break;
        }

        if(d2srf<srfdist){
            vec3 n = normal(p);
            vec3 lightpos = vec3(-3.,3.,-3.);
            float diff = getlight(p,n,lightpos);
            vec3 cdiff = vec3(0.7765, 0.7765, 0.7765);
            
            vec3 fill = dot(normalize(lightpos),n)*vec3(0.3216, 0.3216, 0.3216);

            return fill;
        }
        totdist += d2srf;
    }
    return bg;
}

void main() {
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution;
    uv = uv *2.-1.;

    vec2 mouse = u_mouse.xy / u_resolution;

    vec3 ro = vec3(.5,.0,-5.); //cam pos
    vec2 view = vec2(uv.x+0.,uv.y-.4);
    vec3 rd = normalize(vec3(uv,1.));

    ro = rotate(rotate(ro,vec3(1.,0,0),(mouse.y-.5)*-.5-.2),vec3(0.,1,0),(mouse.x-.5)*2.);
    rd = rotate(rotate(rd,vec3(1.,0,0),(mouse.y-.5)*-.5-.2),vec3(0.,1,0),(mouse.x-.5)*2.);

    vec3 col = raymarch(ro,rd);

    col = pow(col,vec3(1./2.2));
    col = smoothstep(0.,1.,col);
    col = smoothstep(0.,1.,col);
    // float f = 2.;
    // float fo = .5;
    // float off = 6.;

    // col.x = sin(col.x*(f+fo*1.)+off)*.5+.5;
    // col.y = sin(col.y*(f+fo*2.)+off)*.5+.5;
    // col.z = sin(col.z*(f+fo*3.)+off)*.5+.5;
    
    // col = vec3(d);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(col, 1.0);
}

I have tried distorting the space coordinates prior to the modulus calculation, which gives cleaner results. But as soon as I want to move each sphere in more than 1 axis this doesn't work. Conceptually it also makes more sense to move each sphere within each of its local coordinates.
